# Resize Custom Control after Rotation Transformation

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I've got a custom control that draws a graph. A new requirement has arrived, and one part of a solution is rotating the graph. There are other changes inside the control, but these are relatively simple and won't affect this issue.

I can rotate the control as follows:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);

    InitStandard();
    drawXaxis();
    drawYaxis();
    drawZAxis();

    Titles();

    Generate();

    drawGridLines();


    if (UsedAxisType == AxisType.FloorPlot)
    {
        gdRootGrid.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(.5, .5);
        gdRootGrid.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(90);
    }

}
```

This rotates with no problem - I now need to change the width & height of the control to match the new dimensions created with the rotate. I can't do that here as setting the width & height of the control in this event causes a rendering loop.

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
gdRootGrid.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(90);
```

instead.

Comment: @gomi42, at StackOverflow, we are proud to be one of the best coding resources around. As such, minimum standards for questions and answers were devised and *all members* are asked to adhere to them. Your answer(s) fall *far* below that minimum standard. For example, we prefer answers to have more than a few words in them. Please read the [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page from the StackOverflow Help Center for more information. Note that your answers can be deleted by the community if they do not adhere to the standards.